# SQL How to convert date DD-MM-YYYY to MM-YYYY and retrieve most recent records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format

Hi I have to retrieve from my table most recent records that match a given MM-YYYY, but the date field in the table is DD-MM-YYYY, how do I get this done?

Thank you very much

Best Regards
Ignacio.

Comment: What datatype is the column? Char?

Comment: DATETIME is the datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many of the most recent records do you need?

Could you not query for all the dates in the relevant month, order by the dates, and then only select the results you need from the top of the list.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date_time_field >= '20120101' 
  AND date_time_field < '20120201' 
ORDER BY date_time_field DESC
```

This would select the most recent record from January of this year.
Change the number inside the `TOP()` statement to change the number of results returned, or leave it off altogether and take comfort in the fact that your results are ordered.

Comment: Ah, you beat me for 5 seconds.

Comment: @ypercube thanks for the edits. I dont do much raw date formatting for sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
right(select convert(varchar, <date field>, 110), 7)
```

The full query would look someting like this:

```
select *
from table
where right(select convert(varchar, <date field>, 110), 7) = 'MM-YYYY'
```

Comment: Sorry Could help me build the entiry query I noy sure how this part fits in the query

Comment: Why does a datetime column need to be converted to varchar for a comparison?

Comment: Because the comparison is to a string in the format "MM-YYYY".  Did you read the original question?

Comment: @Gordon: Yes, I did. It clearly has: *"records that match a given **MM-YYYY**"* which indicates char and then: *"but the **date** field in the table is **DD-MM-YYYY**"* which indicates a date or datetime column and confusion by the OP about datatypes and formats. I think your answer adds to the OP's confusion, even if it will be an (awfully slow) working query.

Comment: @Gordon, how can I make it work if my period is YYYY-MM, thank you very much!

Comment: How are you representing the period?  It looks like a string to me, which is why I convert the dates into a strong format.

Comment: Oh, for 'YYYY-MM' you would use a more reasonable date format . . . the argument to convert would be 121 and you would take the left 7 characters.  (This is more reasonable because it is the ISO standard.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `your`.`schemaTableNames` WHERE your_coulumn_name LIKE "%-MM-YYYY";
```

should give you the matching records, as you wrote that you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `DateDiff(month, date1, date2) == 0` in your where clause?

This assumes that you can convert both values to DATETIME. If you only have the year and the month, every month has day 01.

Answer (score 0):

to convert a date to desire format you can use style to retrive the records [date formats](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: I would upvote if you were to include some rationale and, perhaps, an example for this. Just giving a link isn't really that helpful.